# How to wire 5 V proximity sensor Ender 3 V2?

Tags: creality-ender-3, creality

I’ve got this proximity sensor which is a 5 V, it doesn’t say it can be used over 5 V. Can I use a buck converter or is it possible to wire it up direct to a 5 V source on the Ender 3 V2?

What I don’t understand is where to wire it direct to 5 V on the printer or if I use a buck converter then where does the 3rd wire go to on the printer?
If it goes to the signal wire on the Z endstop then which one is the signal wire?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Answer (score 1):

## That part seems dubious

Your part is labeled [`LJ18A3-8-Z/BX`](https://www.finglai.com/products/sensors/cylinder-proximity-sensors/M18-8mm/LJ18A3-8-Z_BX.html). That is a Z/BX type sensor of the LJ18A3-8 series - that first part dictates an M18 outer thread and thus dimensions and a triggering distance of 8mm. [Z/BX indicates](https://reprap.world/datasheets/LJ18A3-8-ZBY.pdf) NPN NO, so a normally open sensor of the [NPN type](https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/npn-vs-pnp-in-circuit-design-and-industrial-controls). However, that labeling indicates an inductive sensor with a required **supply voltage of 6 to 36 V** and a power draw of 10 mA between the supply and ground line and a digital output signal of 300 mA.

There is a variant in existence, that has a 5 V supply voltage, but its part number is different by 3 characters: [`LJ18A3-8-Z/BX-5V`](https://www.finglai.com/products/sensors/cylinder-proximity-sensors/M18-8mm/LJ18A3-8-Z_BX-5V.html) - the appended `-5V` is crucial to show it differs from the standard!

## The Ender-3 Board

The Ender-3 board has a 24 V input from the power supply and runs its end-stops on 5 V logic. That would suffice to connect the output of a `LJ18A3-8-Z/BX-5V` sensor directly to a sensor pin.

Comment: Hi I did test it with 5 V source and see if the led comes on near a metal object, and it does and it seems bright, there’s 2 wires going to the end stop and I was wondering how to wire it up?

Comment: @ImranAli then the part is mis-nomed, for wiring it up, you should test the output voltage on the other wires on 5 V input

Comment: There’s quite a lot of sellers selling them and they all say 5 V on the label on lots of websites , so I’m presuming it Is 5 V and most 6 V onwards won’t even work at 5 V but this does actually work at 5 V.

Comment: @ImranAli I would suspect this is the 6V-36V version and the sellers are stretching the truth a bit by claiming it (also) works at 5V. A sensor designed for 6V probably also works at 5V but may or may not be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic attached to the cable shows the wiring for the sensor. There is BN+, BK, BU-; these are presumably the brown, black and blue wires respectively. The schematic BN+ is the positive supply wire (should be connected to 5V) and BU- the negative wire (should be connected to ground). BK is the output wire and should be connected to the endstop signal pin.